# How to Stop a javascript refresh after a set time

Tags: javascript, timer, refresh, max

I have this code to refresh an image at a set interval:

```
<img src="http://somwhere/picture.jpg" id="refreshimage1" onload=”setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'refreshimage1\').src=\'http://somwhere/picture.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds()', 15000)" width="400" border="1" />
```

The problem is, I need the images to refresh every 15 seconds, which works great.  But... I left the webpage open overnight, and today had 15GB of cache in firefox, and no free space on my c:\ drive. (There are about 20 pictures per page, all using this refreshing code.

So, is there a way to add to this code, and make it stop after a set time?  Like after 5 minutes maybe it would stop refreshing images?

Comment: Yes, add logic in to keep track of time.

Comment: Two things, you should move that `onload` login into one of your javascript filess/script element - thats way to much logic for a inline piece of code. Second you don't need to get the image by id as `this` will refer to your image.

Comment: why do u require this 15 second refresh interval? i feel like whatever it is, u can achieve the desire effect without consuming so much bandwidth and cache.

Comment: I think the biggest question here is, if there is a way to delete temporary files, even I am anxious to find the answer.

Comment: Web cam images that need to be refreshed.  Might be a different topic, but a better solution seems to be a way to force the browser to get a new image, and overwrite the one in the cache.  That way it wouldn't fill up a cache with new images.  Is there a way to make it download a new image, but rename it something fixed after doing so, so the cache will always be the same?

Answer (score 0):

Working and tested code. It will refresh your image only for 5 times.

```
<img src="http://somwhere/picture.jpg" id="refreshimage1" onload="fnSetTimer()" width="400" border="1" />
```

Put this function inside your script tag.

```
var c = 0;  

function fnSetTimer()
{
 //do whatever you want to do here.
 //document.getElementById('refreshimage1').src = 'http://somwhere/picture.jpg?\'' + new Date().getMilliseconds();
alert("testing");
var t = setTimeout(fnSetTimer,15000);
c=c+1;
if(c>5)
clearTimeout(t);
}
```

Might be this will help you.

Comment: Hey Mike, can't seem to get the refresh to actually work.  But my old line code to refresh still works.  What am I missing?  I'll paste my code below in another comment due to space (sorry about the formatting, it forced it all together)

Comment: <script>
var c = 0;  

function fnSetTimer()
{
 document.getElementById(\'refreshimage1\').src=\'http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds();
var t = setTimeout(fnSetTimer,5000);
c=c+1;
if(c>5)
clearTimeout(t);
}
</script>

<img src="http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg" id="refreshimage1" onload="fnSetTimer()" width="400" border="1" />

<img src="http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg" id="refreshimage2" onload="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'refreshimage2\').src=\'http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds()', 5000)" width="400" border="1" />

Comment: i gusse problem is in your image url. -----document.getElementById('refreshimage1').src=\'68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds();  ----- plz make sure ur url of the image is correct.

Comment: no need to put '/' in getElementById. Check ur url of the image or search in google how to get image from url by javascript.\

Comment: I've verified the URL is good, and tried it using a few different ones that all go to an image that is updated every few seconds.  In the code I put in the comment above, if you can try it, you'll see the bottom image refreshes correctly, every 5 seconds.  Any thoughts are appreciated! Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
var c = 0;  
function fnSetTimer()
{
alert("testing");
var t = setTimeout(fnSetTimer,15000);
c=c+1;
if(c>5)
clearTimeout(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is where I am at now.  Using the timer function, can't get the image to refresh.

```
<script>
var c = 0;
function fnSetTimer()
{
document.getElementById('refreshimage1').src='http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds();
var t = setTimeout(fnSetTimer,5000);
c=c+1; 
if(c>5) 
clearTimeout(t); 
} 
</script>
<img src="http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg"; id="refreshimage1" onload="fnSetTimer()" width="400" /> 

<img src="http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg"; id="refreshimage2" onload="setTimeout('document.getElementById(\'refreshimage2\').src=\'http://68.116.42.142:8080/cam_4.jpg?\'+new Date().getMilliseconds()', 5000)" width="400" />
```

The second img src code is the original code that refreshes the image, and still works.  Placed side by side, you can see the top image is static, and the bottom image continues to update every 5 seconds.  So the URL to the image is fine, just something is missing to make it refresh in the timer script?